# How to make a class that uses templates deal with a int and a string?

Tags: c++, templates

I'm quite new to templates in C++ and I've been trying to make a list array that holds both a number and a name using templates. I'm using an existing example code that stores a number and I'm trying to adapt it to add a string.

Here is the example code : http://pastebin.com/4sZ6PxcQ

I tried adding a second variable with data type T and added it to all the same places where the items variable was but it didn't work because it was two different datatypes. Any suggestions for doing this? I had some other ideas but I'm quite new using templates so I'm not sure they would work as I visualize them.

I must have it so both the number and the name are saved in the same array. All using templates.

Comment: Learn the basic first. From your code, it looks that you need to learn the basic first, instead of writing your own class template.

Comment: So basically a `ListArray<std::pair<std::string, T>>` (or a pair-like struct with better member names like `name` and `value`)?

Answer (score 0):

Just store both entries in your last as a `pair` or `tuple`.

```
#include <utility>
typedef std::pair<int, std::string> IntAndString;
ListArray<IntAndString> aList;

bool success;

aList.insert(0, std::make_pair(10, "Ten"), success);
aList.insert(1, std::make_pair(8, "Eight"), success);

IntAndString out;
aList.retrieve(1, out, success);

cout << out.first << " " << out.second << "\n";
```

Is this `ArrayList` class something you wrote yourself?  If this isn't homework, I'd suggest using a data structure from the `STL` such as `std::list` or `std::vector` for your needs.  The implementation of `ArrayList` itself is a little clunky (sending in a return result by reference?)

For this to work with your specific implementation, you'll need an appropriate "stream insertion operator" `operator <<` for the above `IntAndString` type to use in the `ArrayList::print` function.

Comment: Its homework. Probably using what you recommend would be considered too advanced. Perhaps using the struct would do the trick as K-ballo suggested. I'm going to try it out and see if it works. If not I'll try your method. Thanks for the help.

Comment: If it is homework and you were responsible for writing the `ArrayList` class, may I suggest that instead of passing in the `success` flag into every function, you have the appropriate functions return the successful status?  Thinking about `insert()` and `retrieve()` specifically.

Comment: The homework tells me to use this particular ArrayList included in a example. I'm supposed to use the example and implement any additional changes to make it work for a problem that usually uses a structure. But I have to write it as a class instead. I'm pretty sure I can move the success around as long as the implementation is similar.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't checked your code, but if you want a list where each element is composed of an int and a string create an aggregate (for instance, a `struct`) that holds both elements and create a list of such aggregate. Alternatively, you could be using a `std::pair< int, std:: string >` as element.